# Pedometer "Unable to parse message when checking for availability!"

Tags: ios, swift, pedometer

I'm using pedometer in an iOS app. And I'm getting 2 message in the console log.

> [Generic] Error on message reply (Connection invalid) [Pedometer]
>
> Unable to parse message when checking for availability!

I didn't find anything related in Apple Documentation.

My code is:

```
    self.pedometerManager = CMPedometer()

    if(CMPedometer.authorizationStatus() == .authorized) {
        
        self.pedometerManager.queryPedometerData(from: self.date, to: self.date.addingTimeInterval(1), withHandler: { [weak self] (result, error) in
            
            if(result != nil) {
                print(result)
                self?.pedometerSteps = result!.numberOfSteps
                self?.pedometerDistance = result!.distance
                
                self?.setupData()
                
            }
            
            completion?()
            
        })
    } else {
        
        completion?()
        

    }
```

This code works, and I get the pedometer result, but the message appear in the console log.
Does anyone know what it is? Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you find the reason?

Comment: @bartl no I didn't understand what happens yet

Comment: Hi, I've found what was the reason in my case. CMPedometer object was released during the queryPedometerData call.

Comment: I will check my code but can be it. Thanks